# Laravel Eloquent whereTime() shows null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query to get the events after the the current time and it shows as `null`. I think the `whereTime` condition is not working or I have a typo.

```
$query = Model::where('id', $request->id)
                ->where('status_id', 1)
                ->whereTime('event_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
                ->first();
```

When I don't have the `whereTime` condition and check the results, it shows this result

```
$query = Model::where('id', $request->id)
                ->where('status_id', 1)
                // ->whereTime('event_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
                ->first();

dd(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $query->event_date);
```

Result

```
"2020-04-15 20:07:43"
"2020-05-23 18:00:00"
```

Comment: Problem is whereTime compares only times, no full date + time.

Comment: @Autista_z thank you for your answer, that must be the case. Do you know any condition for both Date and Time, or I can use two saparate conditions, whereDate and whereTime?

Comment: `->where('event_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('format_you_have_in_db'))` like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your date like this "2021-03-21 13:33:52" then separate date and time like below

```
$date = Carbon::parse($timestamp)->format('Y-m-d');
$time = Carbon::parse($timestamp)->toTimeString();
```

Now you got date and time separated and write query to desire model like below:

```
User::where('status', 1)->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date)
      ->whereTime('created_at', '>', $time)->get();
```

Hope this will help you. This works for me